# Why POI (excel file) created different on different ubuntu systems

Tags: ubuntu, apache-poi

I have two servers each one different version of ubuntu.
One is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS and the second is Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.
I have on each one of them a same jar that creates excel file with content.

In the excel I putting values with currency with format: `String.format("%s #,##0.00", currency)`

The problem is that the Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS create different format from Ubuntu 16.04.6.

The Ubuntu 16.04.6 cell look like "**$ 10.02**" - and this is good.
The Ubuntu 18.04.5 cell look like "**10.02**" - and this isn't good.

And also when I upload the files in Google Drive the excel file from the Ubuntu 18.04.5 is changes all the cells with the currency to **!#VALUE**.

Can any one know this issue?

Thanks

Comment: What versions of Apache POI are you using on the two machines?

Comment: Apache POI 4.1.2 version

Comment: Have you checked to ensure that there aren't older POI versions on one of the classpath? It does sound a bit like what can happen if you have multiple versions by accident

Comment: It the same jar on the machines. How it can be?